# Removing quotes and replacing commas by semicolons in Win batch (bat) script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm sorry but I stuck with windows batch script. I have two input files delimited by comma and additionally with quotes:

File 1 contains only header and 1 row with data

```
"PROVID","CUST_ID","PONUMBER","FORM","Col5","CUST_ID2","Col7","Date","Date2","Col10","Col11","Col12","Col13"
"1111","5290000","00000008","19CFOR0002226","","","","2020-11-20","2020-11-23","","","",""
```

File 2 contains order items related to previous order:

```
"ProductCode","Name","Quantity","FOC","Col5","Discount"
"49370","Product1","12.0","0.0","","0.0"
"142303","Product2","10.0","1.0","","50.0"
"142302","Product3","13.0","2.0","","15.0"
```

This is my script which is merging mentioned files into single file, removing quotes and replacing comma with semicolon.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "outputFile=test.csv"


(for /f tokens^=1-13*skip^=1usebackqdelims^=^,^" %%a in ("Order.csv") do (
        echo(%%a;%%b;%%c;%%d;09100001;%%b;%%h;%%i;2;0;0;I
    ))>%outputFile%

    
(for /f tokens^=1-7*skip^=1usebackqdelims^=^,^" %%a in ("OrderItem.csv") do (
        echo(%%a;%%b;%%c;%%d;S;%%f
    ))>>%outputFile%
```

**Problem which I'm not able solve for last few days:**

1. Date in columns Date and Date2 is not displayed in output file - I guess it is matter of delimiter user in for loop
2. From second file last column is not displayed - the same as above. I guess `^,^"` is incorrect for last column as a delimiter.

This is what I'm receiving:

```
1111;5290000;00000008;19CFOR0002226;09100001;5290000;;;2;0;0;I
49370;Product1;12.0;0.0;S;
142303;Product2;10.0;1.0;S;
142302;Product3;13.0;2.0;S;
```

How it should looks like:

```
1111;5290000;00000008;19CFOR0002226;09100001;5290000;2020-11-20;2020-11-23;2;0;0;I
49370;Product1;12.0;0.0;S;0.0
142303;Product2;10.0;1.0;S;50.0
142302;Product3;13.0;2.0;S;15.0
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: remove `"` from the delimiters and remove them with `%%~a` etc. instead. In your version `","","","","` is treated as *one* delimiter only (consecutive delimiters are treated as one)

Comment: `for /f "tokens=1-13* skip=1 usebackq delims=," %%a in ("Order.csv") do ( echo(%%~a;%%~b;%%~c;%%~d;09100001;%%~b;%%~h;%%~i;2;0;0;I

Comment: Here is another tool to put in your quiver.  [ParseCSV.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5702)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify `,` and `"` as delimiters every sequence of such, like `","","`, for instance, is collapsed into a single delimiter, hence line 2 of file 1 holds 6 tokens, and lines 2, 3, etc. of file 2 hold 5 tokens:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "outputFile=test.csv"

(for /F usebackq^ skip^=1^ tokens^=1-6^ delims^=^,^"^ eol^= %%a in ("Order.csv") do (
    echo(%%a;%%b;%%c;%%d;09100001;%%b;%%e;%%f;2;0;0;I
)) > "%outputFile%"
    
(for /F usebackq^ skip^=1^ tokens^=1-5^ delims^=^,^"^ eol^= %%a in ("OrderItem.csv") do (
    echo(%%a;%%b;%%c;%%d;S;%%e
)) >> "%outputFile%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

To be more robust with respect to potentially (non-)empty items, you could just use `,` as the only delimiter (as long as your data cannot contain such, of course), then use the [`~`-modifier](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) to remove the quotes around each item:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "outputFile=test.csv"

(for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1-4,8-9 delims=, eol=," %%a in ("Order.csv") do (
    echo(%%~a;%%~b;%%~c;%%~d;09100001;%%~b;%%~e;%%~f;2;0;0;I
)) > "%outputFile%"
    
(for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1-4,6 delims=, eol=," %%a in ("OrderItem.csv") do (
    echo(%%~a;%%~b;%%~c;%%~d;S;%%~e
)) >> "%outputFile%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

The above code does not extract unneeded tokens, but of course you may do so for possibly easier association with their original position in the input files:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "outputFile=test.csv"

(for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1-9 delims=, eol=," %%a in ("Order.csv") do (
    echo(%%~a;%%~b;%%~c;%%~d;09100001;%%~b;%%~h;%%~i;2;0;0;I
)) > "%outputFile%"
    
(for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1-6 delims=, eol=," %%a in ("OrderItem.csv") do (
    echo(%%~a;%%~b;%%~c;%%~d;S;%%~f
)) >> "%outputFile%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you a lot. I forgot that I can remove quotes during saving them to the file. Fighting with delimiters is very hard.

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve such a problem is to let the for-loop show all parameters it gets from the input files. Then it is just a matter of checking where you have used the wrong parameter(s).

```
(
(for /f tokens^=1-15*skip^=1usebackqdelims^=^,^" %%a in ("Order.csv") do (
        echo(pa:%%a;pb:%%b;pc:%%c;pd:%%d;pe:%%e;pf:%%f;pg:%%g;ph:%%h;pi:%%i;pj:%%j;pk:%%k;pl:%%l;pm:%%m;pn:%%n;po:%%o;pq:%%p;%%q
    )
(for /f tokens^=1-15*skip^=1usebackqdelims^=^,^" %%a in ("OrderItem.csv") do (
        echo(pa:%%a;pb:%%b;pc:%%c;pd:%%d;pe:%%e;pf:%%f;pg:%%g;ph:%%h;pi:%%i;pj:%%j;pk:%%k;pl:%%l;pm:%%m;pn:%%n;po:%%o;pq:%%p;%%q
    )
)>"LogAllPar.txt"
```

The 2 dates are in `%%e` and `%%f`.
The last column in the second for-loop is in `%%e`.